# Azure Container Apps Login Flow

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-container-apps

**Context**

- I am trying to setup a basic app based upon this todo template with a front-end web app and a back end server https://github.com/azure-samples/todo-python-mongo-aca

**Goal**

- I would like the user to be able to 1. login using google 2. use an id associated with their google account to access their data in my database

**What I've tried to follow**

- I would like a home page for unauthenticated users so I am trying to follow the Without provider SDK flow outlined here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/authentication

**What I have tried**

- Login flow - which successfully displays the google login page (although only if i delete cache)

```
<BaseButton href={`/.auth/login/google?post_login_redirect_uri=/login-redirect`}>
  Login with Google redirect
</BaseButton>
```

I can also see `AppServiceAuthSession`, `ai_session` and `ai_user` cookies in developer tools in browser

- Call server flow = I have one method which doesn't need user information and I'm able to successfully call my backend and return something. There is another flow which involves saving some information specific to the user which I have setup as follows

```
export class UserService {
    protected client: AxiosInstance;

    public constructor(baseUrl: string, baseRoute: string) {
        this.client = axios.create({
            baseURL: `${baseUrl}${baseRoute}`,
        });
    }

    public async saveSelectedFrameworks(frameworks: QueryResponse[]): Promise<QueryResponse[]> {
        const response = await this.client.request<QueryResponse[]>({
            method: 'POST',
            data: frameworks,
        });
        return response.data;
    }
}
```

Note I did try setting `withCredential` in AxiosInstance to true but then I got the following error

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ca-api-XXXXX.eastus.azurecontainerapps.io/save-frameworks' from origin 'https://ca-web-XXXXXX.eastus.azurecontainerapps.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

- My backend server is setup as

```
app = FastAPI(
    description="Cnstlltn App",
    version="0.0.1",
    title="Cnstlltn App",
    docs_url="/",
)
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=originList(),
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["POST"],
    allow_headers=["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
    expose_headers=["*"],
)
```

where my route is written as

```
@app.post("/save-frameworks", response_model=List[UserFramework], status_code=201)
async def save_frameworks(request: Request, saveFrameworks: List[Framework]) -> List[UserFramework]:
    user_id = request.headers.get("X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID")
    results = []
    for framework in saveFrameworks:
        results.append(await UserFramework(userid=user_id, title=framework.title, content=framework.content).save())
    return results
```

this code fails as it cannot find the `x-ms-client-principal-id` I was hoping would be injected in the headers after I had logged in.

- Azure portal. In the azure portal I set my web app authentication to be
- [image: List item]

and ingress to
[image]

whilst in my backend I do not see authentication to anything and for ingress I use the same setting as web - namely insecure connections not allowed and client certificate mode to ignore

**Next steps**
I feel like what I'm trying to do is very basic but I am new to making websites so feeling completely lost at sea. Any suggestions/advice would be much appreciated. These are a few options I am considering

- Try to call `/.auth/me` endpoint from the server itself?
- Switch to full easy-auth but then I lose out on the home page
- Maybe call SDK as suggested in container-apps/authentication web link - although this should only be necessary for rest-apis and non-browsers apps?